# Getting FirePHP working in Kohana 3.1

Tags: firebug, kohana, firephp

I think I've successfully installed the FirePHP module in Kohana 3.1 but I'm not getting any output to the FireBug console.

I've tried this:

```
FirePHP::log('test');
```

and got this error:

```
Non-static method FirePHP::log() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.
```

When I turn off the module and run FirePHP manually:

```
require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
fb('test');
```

Nothing shows up in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception message says, you shouldn't call that method statically, but like :

```
FirePHP::getInstance()->log('test');
```

Few days ago static Fire helper class was added, so now you can do:

```
Fire::log('test');
```

https://github.com/kemo/kohana-firephp

Another possible problem can be Firebug 1.8 because the current FirePHP add-on version doesn't work with it. You can update your add-on [here](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/FinalRelease.htm)

Comment: A reply from the man himself. :) Thanks Kemo. I think it must have been a combination of firebug 1.8 and incorrect usage. Looks great. Thanks again.